# c# mvc 5 error while adding a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

In my mvc project I want to add a controller with views, using Entity Framework. I'm doing it with this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Altough I keep getting this frustrating error
[image]

I rebuilded my project many, many times. I tried some solutions I found in the Internet like [Adding A New MVC 5 Controller with Views Using Entity Framework Scaffolding Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703019/adding-a-new-mvc-5-controller-with-views-using-entity-framework-scaffolding-erro)
or reinstalling my nuget package, restarting Visual Studio, checking my conecctiong string (which seems alright btw), adding new model, etc. I have no idea what to do next, that's why I'm asking You for help.

I use:

- Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7
- .NET Framework 4.6.2

My model code:

```
 public class UserResModel
   {
       [Display(Name = "ReservationID")]
       public int ReservationID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Class")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "When")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ClassWhen { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cancel reservation")]
    public bool CancelRes { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Does your model have a default constructor? Could you show the model code?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm editing my question with the code

Comment: Set your web project to be the startup project

Comment: Unfortunately id didn't help :( I'm stil getting the same error

Comment: Have you tried my below answer?

Comment: Probably these solutions may help: http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2015/06/22/how-to-fix-common-errors-using-asp-net-mvc-scaffolding/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920837/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-in-vs-2013-scaffolding.

Comment: @mb yes I did, it also didn't work

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thankyou for the article, but it didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 'Key' attribute to your ReservationID property. Scaffolding requires a Key to work when it auto generates the controller code.

```
[Key]
[Display(Name = "ReservationID")]
public int ReservationID { get; set; }
```

Once you add that, rebuild the project and try the scaffolding again.

Comment: Unfortunately id didn't help :( I'm stil getting the same error

Comment: If you are using the scaffold controller with entity framework and views option you will need to add a DbSet<ClassRes> auto property to your DbContext class as well (In the default project this is called ApplicationDbContext) once adding that do a rebuild and try again.